# What is the use of last--; here?

Tags: c++, algorithm, iostream, bubble-sort

I am new to C++ as well as algorithm, can anyone helps explain me the use of the (`last--;`) in the middle of my code? The explanation I have got is every times the array pass through will add one more value, so we need to put a `last--` out there. I have tried to remove it, it doesn't affect anything, so is there a necessary to put a `last--;`?

```
void bubbleSort(int array[], int size)
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;
    int last = size - 1;    

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for (int count = 0; count < last; count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {               
                temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }

        last--; 

    } while (swap != false);
}
```

Comment: The final semicolon (after `while`, I presume), is totally necessary, and you can't omit it.  To which semicolon were you referring?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an optimization. You know that the end of the array is sorted, so after each pass you don't have to search as far. But that's just a guess. It "doesn't affect anything" because that part is already sorted anyway.

Comment: it is used to repeat the inner loop each time one time less than the previous, so you don't consider the element you just moved at the end. anyway, as you tried, it's not strictly necessary, it's just for "efficiency" (in very large array maybe it could have some benefit).

Answer (score 4):

> I have tried to remove it, it doesn't affect anything,

Well, have you tested performance?

Try a huge array and measure the time it takes to sort with and without that line.

The line makes sure that the inner loop doesn't visit numbers that already have been sorted.

If you delete the line, the inner loop will iterate `size` times every time. In worst case that will give `size x size` iterations.

With the line, the inner loop will iterate `size` times first, then `size-1`, then `size-2`...  In worst case that will give `size x (size-1) / 2` iterations, i.e. aprox. half the iterations and thereby better performance.

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loop of your algorithm loops array elements and swaps adjacent elements if `a[i]>a[i+1]`. After one pass of this loop, the last element passed over must surely be the largest of all elements looped over, it has been bubbled up. So, in the next round of the `while` loop, the `for` loop does not have to consider this element again. This is ensured by `last--`. 
If you remove that line, the algorithm will work, but will do twice as many comparisons, all of which are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is merely an optimization of the algorithm.

After each pass, the far part the array becomes sorted. So we don't need to check it anymore. Since the `for` loop is based on `limit`, adding `limit--;` just contracts the loop.

> I have tried to remove it, it doesn't affect anything, so is there a necessary to put a last--;?

No, it is not for the algorithm to work. It will work just as happily without it. It just purely an optimization that will have an impact on performance, especially with larger arrays.